# How to track inexistent images request

Tags: images

My server CPU is running high and one of the reasons is that it is requesting these images that don't even exist.

How can I track and find what exactly is requesting them?

[image]

Comment: Server access logs would show you that. However, are these images that USE to exist and no longer do? or just random requests?

Comment: Random requests. That's why I am. lost.

Comment: Caching 404 can help. Though I would start with iTheme, WordFence and Sucuri. Makes it easy to see repeated and start with a base ban list.

Comment: sure that these images are not somewhere in database or maybe in CSS or JS?